# Asserting the LineBreaks in test ng

Tags: testng

I am trying to compare the text I have in GUI to that inside a text file using testNG asserts. The GUI source code is as below

```html
<h2>What is EAC?</h2>
                        <br/>
                        The Effective Annual Cost (EAC) is a measure ....(text continues...)
[enter image description here][1]
```

My text file is like

What is EAC?

The Effective Annual Cost (EAC) is a measure ....(text continues...)

The assertion fails and the comparator shows difference in white space characters(Apologies for not attaching the image. I still do not have permission to do so)

I tried to add \n in my text file where there is a line break as I saw in the forum, but of no use.

How can I assert properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Issue solved. My mistake was in the Java code I was using to read the text file. 

public String readTextfile(String fileFullPath){
     BufferedReader reader= null;
     StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

         try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (fileFullPath));      
            String         line = null;
            //String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            // System.out.println("Line separator is "+ls);

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  stringBuilder.append(line);
                  //stringBuilder.append(ls);
                  stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }


      } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }finally {
        try{
            reader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My code was reading the line separator using System.getProperty("line.separator") and appending to the line. I had to replace it with appending a new line (\n) as shown in the above code.